# If $\phi\in W^U$ and if $\psi\in W^V$ and if $W$ is a topological vector space then $f(u,v):=\phi(u)+_{_{W}}(-1)*_{_{W}}\psi(v)$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

**Statement**

Let be $W$ a topological vector space and $\phi:U\rightarrow W$ and $\psi:V\rightarrow W$ two continuous functions. So if we define $f:U\times V\rightarrow W$ though the condition
$$
1.\quad f(u,v):=\phi(u)+_{_{W}}(-1)*_{_{W}}\psi(v)
$$
for any $u\in U$ and for any $v\in V$ then $f$ is continuous in the product topology.

Unfortunately I can't prove the statement: I have proved to show that $f$ is composition of continuous functions defining the function $\Delta:U\times V\rightarrow W\times W$ through the condition
$$
\Delta(u,w):=\big(\phi(u),\psi(v)\big)
$$
that for the universal mapping theorem for products is continuous (**is this correct**?) but then I can't continue because, although I see that $f(u,v)=+_{_{W}}\Big(\phi(u),*_{_{W}}\big(-1,\psi(v)\big)\Big)$, I can't prove that the function $\tilde\Delta:U\times V\rightarrow W\times W$ defined through the condition
$$
\tilde\Delta(u,v)=\Big(\phi(u),*_{_{W}}\big(-1,\psi(v)\big)\Big)
$$ for any $u\in U$ and $v\in V$ is continuous. Naturally $+_{_{W}}$ is the vectorial sum in $W$ and $*_{_{W}}$ is the scalar multiplication in $W$. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Can you see that $(w_1, w_2) \mapsto (w_1, -w_2)$ is continuous?

Comment: @DanielFischer This is my the problem!!!!

Comment: Can you see that $w \mapsto -w$ is continuous?

Comment: @DanielFischer Ceratinly it seems obviuous but I doubt. Excuse me, but the problem is that I want prove formally any result.

Comment: By definition of a topological vector space, the scalar multiplication $K \times W \to W$ is continuous. Thus the restriction to the (topological) subspace $\{ -1\} \times W$ is also continuous.

Comment: @DanielFischer Right the **restriction**!!! Now it is clear.

Comment: So who's going to write an answer, you or I?

Comment: @DanielFischer I'd like if you'll answer because I'd like to know your point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write $f$ as the composition of simpler maps in the form $f = +_W \circ s \circ \Delta$, where the addition $+_W$ is continuous by the definition of topological vector spaces, the map $\Delta \colon (u,v) \mapsto (\phi(u),\psi(v))$ is continuous by general properties of maps between product spaces, and $s \colon (w_1, w_2) \mapsto (w_1, -w_2)$ remains to be seen as continuous.

Again by general properties of maps between product spaces, the continuity of $s$ is equivalent to the continuity of the negation map $n \colon W \to W$, $n(w) = -w$. We can write this as the composition
$$w \mapsto (-1,w) \mapsto (-1)\ast_W w = -w$$
of the embedding $W \to \{-1\}\times W \subset K \times W$ and the scalar multiplication $K \times W \to W$. The embedding is continuous since each component is, and the scalar multiplication is continuous by definition of a TVS. Hence $n$ is continuous, and thus $s$ is continuous, and finally the continuity of $f$ follows.